# How to use the client certification with selenium + python + chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pem, p12

How do I access a website that requires client authentication?

My environment is below:

- Python 3.7.1
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Chrome 73 (Chromedriver)

And I have a p12 file. I can extract a pem file using openssl command.
Could you tell me how to access website using the Selenium.

By the way, I can convert the p12 file I have to a pem file and access that website with the Requests library.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! I edited to draw people's eyes toward the question. Also, it might be helpful to show what has been tried and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Have you come across [this tutorial](https://www.robbiecode.com/use-browser-client-certificate-with-selenium-and-phantomjs/)?

Comment: @char thats PhantomJS's solution, not ChromeDriver

Comment: @Jim good point, I missed that